# 1 and 0 are present in an empty int array

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, undefined

Can someone point me to what is wrong and the values 0 and 1 always go in the `if` and return true. (Assume the array is empty).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

int getUserInput(int position){
    printf("Please enter an integer for the %d position of the array\n", position);
    int input;
    scanf(" %d", &input);
    return input;
}

bool hasValue(int value, int array[ARRAY_SIZE]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){

        if (value == array[i]){
            printf("This value already exists in the array.\n");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

main(){
    int array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int index = 0;

    while (index < ARRAY_SIZE ){
        int input = getUserInput(index);

        if (!hasValue(input, array)){
            array[index] = input;
            index++;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing "wrong".  Post enough to show how `array[]` is populated and show how `hasValue()` is called: [MCVE].

Comment: what means "the array is empty"?  Do you mean "uninitialized"?

Comment: Nothing is lethally wrong with the code you've shown, but the function will only ever work with array s of exactly size `ARRAY_SIZE`.

Comment: There is something wrong between my understanding and what is actually happening :P I edited and added more code in the question.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "empty" array. You haven't shown us how `ARRAY_SIZE` and `getUserInput` are defined. If you examine values that haven't been initialized, the behavior is undefined, and you'll most likely get garbage values. `0` and `1` are just as much garbage as any other values.

Comment: @KeithThompson I did update the code once more

Comment: In `hasValue` you should use `i < index` instead of `i < ARRAY_SIZE`, because that is how many values you have.

Comment: the statement: `main()` will cause the compiler to output amessage about the lack of a 'return type'.  In years gone by (I.E. earlier versions of C) it would default to `int`  However, that is nolonger the case.  Suggest using: `int main( void )`

Comment: @BoPersson `index` is not visible to the function `hasValue`.

Comment: when asking about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve].   The currently posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements (and we are not mind readers as to what header files are actually included)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, please consistently indent the code.  Note: the `{}` button will do that (mostly) for you.

Comment: @hafeez - Right, the code code might need some refactoring. :-)

Comment: @user3629249 I added the `#include` Concerning the indentation I do not get what you mean. I do not see any indentation problems, but you are welcome to edit my post

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `int array[ARRAY_SIZE];`  the array will contain what ever junk is on the stack at that location of the array.  Suggest something similar to: `int array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};`  which would initialize the array to all 0

Comment: @user3629249 After initializing `1` works, but `0` still returns `true` in `hasValue`

Comment: so, change the initialization to a value that the user cannot (easily) enter.  for instance: `int array[ARRAY_SIZE]; memset( array, '0xFE', sizeof( array ) );`

Comment: @user3629249: Many C compilers will not complain about implicit `int` declarations by default. (I consider this unfortunate.) If you want a conforming C compiler, you usually have to add explicit options.

Comment: @user3629249: I don't think the `{}` button will fix indentation. It just indents a block of text by 4 columns. It doesn't know what language the text is in, so it has no way of knowing how to fix it.

Comment: You added the `#include` directives and the definitions of `ARRAY_SIZE` and `getUserInput`. Why did you then delete them?

Comment: @KeithThompson because these had nothing to do with the problem. The problem was that the `for` in `hasValue` was checking parts of the array not assigned a value yet.

Comment: I've rolled back your most recent edit. Without a complete program, it's impossible to tell whether the problem is in the code you've shown us or in the code you haven't shown us. Please read this: [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be better to pass the array `size` as parameter to the function instead of fixing it. like

```
bool hasValue(int value, int array[], unsigned int size)
```

As your `ARRAY_SIZE` is a constant thus the for loop inside the function always executes `ARRAY_SIZE` times.

**EDIT**
If you still didn't solved the issue with your code. Replace the relevant code with this and try

```
bool hasValue(int value, int array[], int size) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (value == array[i]) {
            printf("This value already exists in the array.\n");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int index = 0;

    while (index < ARRAY_SIZE ) {
        int input = getUserInput(index);

        if (!hasValue(input, array, index)) {
            array[index] = input;
            index++;
        }

     }

     return 0;
}
```